# Numerical Determination of Generating Functions from Recursion Relations

Tags: co.combinatorics, computer-algebra

Are there computer packages which calculate coefficients of generating functions, such as

$$D_n(q)=\sum_m d_{m,n}q^m= \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n (1-q^i)^2} \text{ or}$$

$$S_d(q)=\sum_m s_{m,d}q^m = \frac{q^d}{\prod_{i=1}^d (1-q^i)} \; ?$$

The effort, to calculate all coefficients e.g. $d_{k,l}$ for $k$ and $l$ smaller than $N$ should grow with $N^3$, 
as they satisfy recursion relations such as

$$d_{m,n} = \sum_{k=0}^{[m/n]}(k+1)d_{m-k\cdot n,n-1}$$

which allow to express each of the $N^2$ coefficients as a sum of at most $N$ terms 
($d_{m,1}=m+1$, $d_{0,0}=1$, $d_{m,0}=0$ for $m>0$).

Before I revive my rusty computer knowledge I would like to know whether
computer packages such as GAP tackle my problem to solve recursion
relations with given initial conditions, save the solutions to files and allow 
to read them in again if one wants to tackle the next case $N+1$.

Comment: Regarding the question itself, AFAIK, sage itself does not do generating functions per se; but, in this context, I can see a much simpler algorithmic code, which is based on the observation that I can truncate $(1 - q^i)^{-1}$ after a certain index that is an easy-to-figure function of $m$. So, there are ways to handle this, but, thinking of them as generating functions as such is not going to help make matters nice.

Comment: @qknsam: Isn't the truncation which you suggest the content of the recursion relation, 
$D_n(q) = (1-q^n)^{-2} D_{n-1}(q)$, $(1-q^n)^{-2}=\sum_k (k+1)q^{k\cdot n}$ ?

Comment: I know I have used Maple to calculate similar things, but as I am currently without Maple access I can't test it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Bruno Salvy (et al's) [gfun](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/bruno.salvy/?page_id=48) package.

Answer (score 0):

In Maple you can do

```
series(mul((1-q^i)^(-2),i=1..10),q=0,1000)
```

to get $D_{10}(q)$ as far as $q^{999}$; this took 0.9 seconds on my laptop.  Alternatively, you can do

```
d := proc(m,n)
 option remember;

 if n = 0 then
  if m = 0 then
   return 1;
  else
   return 0;
  fi;
 else
  return add((k+1)*d(m-k*n,n-1),k=0..floor(m/n));
 fi;
end:
```

This calculates $d(1000,10)$ in about 0.9 seconds again.  It remembers all instances of $d(m,n)$ that it has already computed.